# Output PID to file from process executed in bash script?

Tags: bash, mongodb, ubuntu, process, pid

I've got this simple bash script that starts a server process. I want to output the pid of the server process to a file, `pid.txt`. After some quick searching on SO, I came up with this approach, but it seems to give me the pid of the bash script, not the server process executed from the script. Note: the `--fork` is required for my server process to run as a daemon to output data to a separate log file, and I suspect that's causing the issue here based on this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821968/pid-of-last-started-process-in-bash-script), hoping there's a way around this.

```
#! /bin/bash

./mongo-linux64-202/mongod --fork &
pid=$!

printf "%s\n" "$pid" > pid.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might I suggest:

```
#! /bin/bash

./mongo-linux64-202/mongod --pidfilepath ./pid.txt --fork &
```

derived from Mongo help:

```
mongod --help
```

Comment: Tried that, but it does not create the file...  `#! /bin/bash

./mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2/bin/mongod --pidfilepath pid.txt --fork --dbpath /opt/mongo/data/db1/dbs --port 33479 --logpath /opt/mongo/data/db1/log/db1.log -logappend &`

Comment: Try making the pidfilepath more explicit: ./pid.txt (or even better /home/raffi/pid.txt or some other appropriate absolute path).  It's possible that mongod is interpreting the relative path as relative to some other directory than your PWD.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, had to be more explicit, changed to `--pidfilepath /opt/mongo/pid.txt`, thanks for the help!

Comment: using --fork puts the process in the background so you never should need & (but you do need to give it path to the log file as --logpath argument

Answer (score -1):

```
./mongo-linux64-202/mongod --fork &
pid=$(jobs -p | tail -n 1)
```

Though look first whether `mongod` is willing to report its pid somehow.

Comment: What exactly does `pid=$(jobs -p | tail -n 1)` do? Does this work if multiple mongo processes are running on the same machine?