# Why are my local commands failing to run after remote ssh commands in the same script?

Tags: bash, ssh

I've done my homework, but I think I may be mixing apples and oranges here. My script is designed to run a remote inline series of commands, exit, and then run some additional LOCAL commands. It has to be done remote first, as these services are for a fail-over agent. The problem is that after the remote ssh line disconnects, the entire script just stops. I'm not sure why the disconnect is halting the entire script. Perhaps the exit line is to blame?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    ### Run remote svc restarts and then Local restarts
    #
    exec ssh -t REMOTEHOST 'stop svc1; restart svc2; start svc3; exit'
    (SCRIPT FAILS HERE)  
    ## Run local shell (This works independently, but not in the entire script)
    rst=`pgrep -n failoversvc`

    echo "Stopping 1st service at `date | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'`" && service 1 stop >> SYNCLOG.txt
          sleep 2
    echo "Restarting 2nd service at `date | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'`" && service 2 restart >> SYNCLOG.txt

    if rst="";then

    echo "Starting 3rd service at `date | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'`" && service 3 start >> SYNCLOG.txt
      else 
        echo "3rd Service PID not found! Check for functionality"
    fi
```

I took a look at but [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543720/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-local-command-after-connection-and-quit-after-this-local) I wasn't able to get the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`exec` is a very brutal command: it completely *replaces* the current process (in this case, your shell that's running the script) with the command you specify. Unless  `exec` fails, nothing after that line in your script will ever run. This is by design, that's what `exec` is for.

If you want your script to continue after the `ssh`, simply remove `exec`.

Comment: Wow.. all because of one small word. Working great now, Thanks much!